# How to return string while it returns not define

Tags: google-apps-script

I got this error when trying to grab messages from Gmail inbox.

```
    ReferenceError: "messages" is not defined.
```

I don't know if there is any other functions fit here better.

```
function getRelevantMessages()
{
  var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:33d", 0, 100);
  var messages=[];
  threads.forEach(function(thread) {
                    messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0]);
                  });
  return messages;
}

if (!messages) {
  //Check if it returns something 
}
```

the code from pastebin 
        https://pastebin.com/TRkEB6yM

Answer (score 1):

In the code you attached to your question, you have an `if` statement that is outside of the `getRelevantMessages()` function. In fact, the error you get (`ReferenceError: "messages" is not defined.`) is not due to any error in the `getRelevantMessages()` function, but rather due to that statement. In order to run your code please do the following:

- Remove any code that is defined outside of declared top-level functions. i.e:

```js
if (!messages) {
  //Check if it returns something 
}
```

- Within the editor, select the function you want to run and click the *play* button to run it. You could declare and use the following function as means of testing:

```js
function main() {
  var messages = getRelevantMessages();
  for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Got message: ' + messages[i].getId());
  }
}
```